# MSAccess - TransferDatabase - File locked open?

Tags: ms-access

I am attempting the following in an AccessDb via VBA:

1. Export a single table from current DB into a new DB in the same directory, via a Query/TransferDatabase.  This seems to work as expected.

   ```
   Dim ws As Workspace
   Dim db_new as Database
   strPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\Backend_Database\"
   strDBFilename = strPath & Raw_Count_File.accdb"

   Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
   Set db_new = ws.CreateDatabase(strDBFilename, dbLangGeneral)

   DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", _
      strDBFilename, acTable, "tmp_RawCountFile", "Raw_TblMatchedTB"
   ```
2. Within the same function used above (to create the new file), I am attempting next to ZIP the new file into the same directory. The result is 1K Byte ZIP file (it's an empty ZIP ).
3. If I breakout the code segment that creates the ZIP file into separate function (i.e., under another button), the function works as expected and the proper ZIP file is created.

My Question:

1. I am guessing the new DB file and subsequent TransferDatabase is leaving the new_db file hanging open and inaccessible to the ZIP function.  I attempted to set the various objects = nothing prior to the ZIP function, but same result.  Only if I exit the first function and call a second function will it work as desired.
2. Can I add something to the end of the TransferDatabase function to ensure the resulting file will be available for the ZIP task?
3. My preference is not to add a secondary button press to this task...

Any suggestions to get me going?

- Thanks!

Comment: After you create your database, wouldn't you have to close out of it?  Something like 'db_new.application.quit'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `Set db_new = Nothing` before zipping, in order to close the newly created db.

Comment: Gahh, you are correct.  "I had Set db = Nothing".  Close but not quite.  That was exactly the issue.  - Thanks!